# How can I tell when a facebook application is uninstalled?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-iframe

I have a PHP iFrame application that needs to clean up data when it is uninstalled from the user's fan page.  Is there a URL callback which happens when the application is uninstalled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [App Deauthorization](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)
>
> When a user of your app removes it in
>   the App Dashboard or blocks the app in
>   the News Feed, your app can be
>   notified by specifying a Deauthorize
>   Callback URL in the Developer App.
>   During app removal we will send an
>   HTTP POST request containing a single
>   parameter, signed_request, which
>   contains the user id (UID) of the user
>   that just removed your app. You will
>   not receive an user access token in
>   this request and all existing user
>   access tokens will be automatically
>   expired.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.  The unicorn is my magic talisman.